# xcode selector not found

Tags: objective-c, xcode, selector

I have written the following statement :

```
int  kk = [MartialArtsCheckInAppPurchaseKey scrambledKey:0];
```

When Xcode executes the statement, it runs to the following crashing exception message.

> 2015-05-22 19:46:02.386 HanDynastyMartialArts[2779:107363] +
>   [MartialArtsCheckInAppPurchaseKey scrambledKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10e824878
>   2015-05-22 19:46:02.390 HanDynastyMartialArts[2779:107363] *** 
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[MartialArtsCheckInAppPurchaseKey scrambledKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10e824878'
>   *** First throw call stack:

In my MartialArtsCheckInAppPurchaseKey.h, I have the following declaration:

```
// extern int  scrambledKey(int n);


@interface MartialArtsCheckInAppPurchaseKey : NSObject {

}

+(int)  scrambledKey:(int) n;
+(BOOL) scrambledMatch: (int) key;


+(int)  getKeyElement:(int) n;
+(int)  getUIDKeyIndex:(int) n;
+(BOOL) checkInAppPurchaseKey: (int)key;
+(void) setInAppPurchaseKey: (int) key : (BOOL) value;

@end
```

The selector that Xcode complained is declared in MartialArtsCheckInAppPurchaseKey.m as follows.

```
- (int)  scrambledKey:(int) n {
  ... 
}
/* scrambledKey */
```

Can someone help me out of this and tell me what was wrong ? 
Also why sometimes we declare methods in the header file with '+' and '-' ? 
What is the difference ?

Thanks

Farn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration for `scrambledKey`:

```
+(int)  scrambledKey:(int) n;
```

tells the compiler that the method is a class one (`+` stands for class methods, `-` stands for instance methods). Thus, at runtime you get the `unrecognised selector` exception as there is no class method named `scrambledKey` (declaring a method doesn't imply the method exists).

However, you're implementing as an instance method. So, depending on your needs, you either have to change the declaration of the method, or it's implementation. Considering the caller code makes use of a class method, changing the method implementation code (simply replacing the `-` by a `+`) would require less modifications. This assuming the implementation doesn't depend on instance members of `MartialArtsCheckInAppPurchaseKey`, case when you're forced to change the definition (replace `+` by `-`, use instances of `MartialArtsCheckInAppPurchaseKey` to call the method).

Answer (score 1):

`-scrambledKey:` is an instance method (not static method).
You need to create an instance of `MartialArtsCheckInAppPurchaseKey` then call the method on it's instance

```
MartialArtsCheckInAppPurchaseKey *obj = [MartialArtsCheckInAppPurchaseKey new]
int  kk = [obj scrambledKey:0];
```

Also please note, that the interface declaration (in MartialArtsCheckInAppPurchaseKey.h file) is wrong, you need to correct it like this

```
// extern int  scrambledKey(int n);


@interface MartialArtsCheckInAppPurchaseKey : NSObject {

}

// NOTE: I've changed + -> -
-(int)  scrambledKey:(int) n;
+(BOOL) scrambledMatch: (int) key;


+(int)  getKeyElement:(int) n;
+(int)  getUIDKeyIndex:(int) n;
+(BOOL) checkInAppPurchaseKey: (int)key;
+(void) setInAppPurchaseKey: (int) key : (BOOL) value;

@end
```